# NSRequest vs initWithURL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, http, rss, nsxmlparser

Should I use `initWithURL` or `NSRequest` to download an XML file when using `NSXMLParser`?

I'm downloading a feed and I'd like to get progress information for my download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out ASIHTTP as that is really good at handling this sort of thing....

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

As pointed out the above is now not supported.  I would recommend looking at AFNetworking instead now.

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: This is looking good in my initial implementation. If this works, we have a winner.

Comment: ASIHTTP isn't supported anymore

Answer (score 0):

Just a sidenote. `initWithUrl` will download the file synchronously. If you want to parse the XML stream on-the-fly, here's an article (plus code) about that matter:

http://benreeves.co.uk/iphone-expat-xml-parser-wrapper/

Comment: Yea, I noticed the synchronous bit. You may have fixed some other issues too with this suggestion... I'll handle that soon and get back to you.

Comment: Hey, @The MYYN - What files do I need to include to use iPhone Expat?

Comment: Sorry, this isn't going to work for me. i couldn't figure out how to make the asynchronous part work.